# formData in React, sending to backend Express recieved null

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, express-fileupload

i'm doing image upload in my mern app and i'm using `express-fileupload` package, in the frontend i'm sending a image in FormData, but backend recives null.

**frontend**

```
const [infos, setInfos] = useState({title: '', text: '', image: ''})

const handleImg = (e) => {
    const { files } = e.target
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('image', files[0])
    setInfos({ ...infos, image: formData.get('file') }) // image is null if i put formData itself 
  }

const submit = async(e) => {
 e.preventDefault()
 console.log(infos) // {title: 'titlw', text: 'text', image: File}
 try{
  await axios.post('/upload', infos, {headers: {'Content_Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
 }
  catch(err) console.log(err)
}


<form onSubmit={submit} enctype='multipart/form-data' >
 <input
      type='file'
      accept='image/*'
      name='image'
      onChange={handleImg}
    />
</form>
```

**backend**

```
import fileUpload from 'express-fileupload'
app.use(fileUpload())

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.files)  // undefined
 console.log(req.body)   // {title: 'value', text: 'value', image: ''}
 // if(req.files){
 //  const {image} = req.files
 //  image.mv(__dirname+'/client/uploads/'+image.name)
 }
})
```

When i check `infos` on the frontend, there is data, but when i requested to Express backend, all the text infos are there, but image is empty in the `req.body` and `req.files` is undefined. I spent alomst all yesterday on this, still can't solve.

Comment: You're storing file information in the state `infos` but you're sending `info` to your post request.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you send wrong const, you set "infos" but you send "info".

Comment: Sorry, i misspelled when i was asking this question but in my real code it is the same